# Why my flickity slider made in full CSS need to be manually resize to work?

Tags: css, flickity

I have a *problem*, I use flickity and **every time i refresh my page, I have to resize my window for the slider** work, and i don't know how to fix it..

I use flickity with the CDN and only in CSS.

I tried properties like "imageLoaded", i tried every solution i could find but no success. (sorry for my english I'm from france)

If someone had a solution, I would be here! :)

```
<body class="bd">
  <header>
    <a href="./index.html" class="return-home"><h1 class="logo">Mélissa Mangin</h1></a>
    <div class="about-link">
      <a href="./about.html" class="link-about"> <img class="icone" src="static/icone-mel/logo3.png" alt="icone Melissa"></a>
    </div>
  </header>
  

  <!-- Flickity HTML init -->
  <div class="carousel"
    data-flickity='{ "cellSelector": ".carousel-cell", "adaptiveHeight": true , "setGallerySize": false , "imagesLoaded": true, "lazyLoad": true }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell">
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="static/carousel-bd/peach-salinger.png">
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <div class="carousel-cell-paragraph">
              <p class="paragraph-first-slide"><span>Objectif : </span>Développer des arcs narratifs d'une série
                télévisée dans une démarche tranmédiatique. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
              <img class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="static/carousel-bd/first-page-bd.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
              <div class="carousel-cell-paragraph">
                <p class="paragraph-first-slide">La série "You" a été choisie. Développement d'un arc narratif
                  autour d'un personnage secondaire afin d'apporter du contenu inédit et supplémentaire aux fans de la
                  série.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">
          <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-inner">
              <div class="flip-card-front">
                <img class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="static/carousel-bd/persos-bd.png">
              </div>
              <div class="flip-card-back">
                <div class="carousel-cell-paragraph">
                <p class="paragraph-first-slide">Rédaction d'une histoire originale centrée sur Peach Salinger. J'ai
                  dessiné l'intégralité des planches de cette BD</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-cell">
        <div class="flip-card">
          <div class="flip-card-inner">
            <div class="flip-card-front">
              <img class="carousel-cell-image" data-flickity-lazyload="static/carousel-bd/planche-bd.png">
            </div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">
              <div class="carousel-cell-paragraph">
              <p class="paragraph-first-slide"><span>Outils utilisés : </span>Tablette graphique, Sketch, Clip Studio
                Paint, Adobe Indesign </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-title">
      <h2 class="title-2">Création d'une bande dessinée</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/glow.js"></script>
  <script src="less/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```